# Multiple send() commands compared to the return of one compound string

Tags: mapreduce, nosql, couchdb

I'm working on a Couch db list view. The output should be a json object  with a structure that's appropriate for the client.

I'm currently creating one compund string from the different elements of the values I get sent to the view function. What it basically does is adding substrings to the result string which is later returned when the function finishes. That does the job for now.

But the list view also has the send() function which sends a value to the output, without ending the list function itself.

What I see is two approaches to the same problem where both can give the exact same output.

1. Accumulate all the intended output and return at the end.
2. Use send() and send each substring to the output before the entire process is done.

I have no idea how couch internally handles those two. Is there a preferred more efficient way? What is the reason for that in that case?

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation say](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later) that you should use the following code template

```
function(head, req) {
  var row;
  start({
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
     }
  });
  while(row = getRow()) {
    send(row.value);
  }
}
```

However this is not always make sense. For example if you calculate MD5 sum, it will be more comfortable to return it when calculations are finished.

So you have to make a decision every time.

Comment: I know, this piece of information is one of the reasons I ask the question. The official wiki have a few places where it makes little to no sense. At least you don't get any clear explanations. And I read that page you refer to as one possible way of doing it, not by any means the only way or the preferred way. Just the way that came to mind while the article was written.